# Converter str(object) para int (python)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Eu tenho um dataset com duas colunas e gostaria de criar uma terceira coluna chamada Ranking que receberá valores baseados na coluna Marca. De forma que a Marca A vai receber o valor 10 e assim por diante.

```
df = {'Marca' : ['A', 'B', 'C'],
 'Valores': ['10', '11', '12']}

df['Ranking'] = df['Marca'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('A','10')
                                          .replace('B', '11')
                                          .replace('C', '12'))
```

Com esta função o código funcionou, porém o dtype da coluna Ranking está como object, aí eu tentei utilizar `df.Ranking.astype(int)`para transformar para inteiro, porém quando dou um `df.dtypes`continua como object. Há uma outra forma para eu tratar isso?? Esta coluna precisa ser numérica, pois vou usá la para modelagem mais adiante. 
Obs: a variável df é um objeto do Pandas. Obrigado.

Comment: Olá @Edi, você poderia editar sua pergunta e adicionar nas tags a biblioteca que você está usando?

Answer (score 1):

Para alterar o tipo de dados necessita de atribuir o resultado da função `astype(int)` de volta à coluna `Ranking`.

Usando os dados do seu exemplo

```
import Pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Marca' : ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'Valores': ['10', '11', '12']})
df['Ranking'] = pdf['Marca'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('A', '10').replace('B', '11').replace('C', '12'))
```

Se verificar qual o tipo de dados vai obter, como indicou na sua pergunta, que `df['Ranking']` tem tipo `object`

```
>>> df.dtypes
Marca      object
Valores    object
Ranking    object
dtype: object
```

Invocando a função astype() e atribuindo o resultado de volta à coluna `df['Ranking']`

```
df['Ranking'] = df['Ranking'].astype(int)
```

Voltando a verificar o tipo de dados, irá obter:

```
>>> df.dtypes
Marca      object
Valores    object
Ranking     int32
dtype: object
```

Comment: Obrigado bruno. Funcionou desta forma. Mais uma que aprendi. Valeu.

Comment: comigo isso náo funciona